# SQL Interest Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have to create a stored proc to calculate interest.

```
 --Sending these parameters to stored proc
 @rec_date date,
 @amount_paid numeric(18,2)
```

The rules are below, there are more rules but I can handle the other ones if I can get this

1. Interest is calculated at a rate of 2% per month using a 30-day month on a pro-rata basis (not compounded).
2. The `@rec_date` is used to determine the days between that date and today
3. Interest is calculated based on the parameter `@amount_paid`
4. If calculated interest `> 5.00` then `interest = calculate interest or else interest = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1547/calculating-mathematical-values-in-sql-server/) to get a feel for doing calculations with TSQL.  Next, a good function to use will be DATEDIFF().  You can find more information on that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).  This should get you going.  Take a stab at it and post your code if you get stumped.